# ¿Como puedo mantener una ListView con sus datos tras volver de otra actividad?

Tags: java, android, listview, activity, android-listview

Estoy haciendo una aplicación de contactos para Android, la verdad soy nuevo en esto. Tengo una `ListView` en la `MainActivity` que debe mostrar los contactos o un mensaje en caso de que no haya contactos y un Floating Action Button, al presionarlo este me lleva a otra actividad con un formulario para crear el contacto, cuando vuelvo a la actividad este aparece, pero al agregar otro contacto el primero desaparece y así es cada que agrego un contacto. ¿Cómo hago para que al guardar el contacto se vayan agregando a la `ListView` de la actividad principal?

El código de mi MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private ArrayList<Contacto> contactos = new ArrayList<>();
private ArrayList<String> nombresContactos = new ArrayList<>();
private ListView lstContactos;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    agregarFab();

    //Inicializa el campo de texto y la lista, pone en la interfaz el campo de texto cuando la lista está vacía:
    TextView tvVacio = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvVacio);
    lstContactos =  (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lstContactos);
    lstContactos.setEmptyView(tvVacio);

    //Agarra datos despues de crear un contacto nuevo y los devuelve para crear un contacto nuevo para la lista:
    try {

        Bundle contacto = getIntent().getExtras();
        String nombre = contacto.getString(getResources().getString(R.string.name));
        String telefono = contacto.getString(getResources().getString(R.string.phone));
        String email = contacto.getString(getResources().getString(R.string.email));
        String date = contacto.getString(getResources().getString(R.string.date));
        String descripcion = contacto.getString(getResources().getString(R.string.description));

        Contacto temp = new Contacto(nombre, date, descripcion, telefono, email);

        if (nombre != null && telefono != null) {
            contactos.add(temp);
            nombresContactos.add(temp.getNombre());
        }

        lstContactos.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, nombresContactos));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        lstContactos.setEmptyView(tvVacio);
    }

}

public void agregarFab() {
    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);

    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent nuevoContacto = new Intent(MainActivity.this, AgregarContacto.class);
            startActivity(nuevoContacto);
        }
    });
}
```

Este es el código de la segunda actividad para agregar el contacto:

```
public class AgregarContacto extends AppCompatActivity {

private EditText etNombre;
private EditText etTelefono;
private EditText etEmail;
private EditText etDate;
private DatePickerDialog dpdFecha;
private EditText etDescription;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_agregar_contacto);

    //Inicializa UI:
    etNombre = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etNombre);
    etTelefono = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etTelefono);
    etEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etEmail);
    etDate = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etDate);
    etDate.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NULL);
    etDescription = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etDescription);

    iniciarPicker();

    etDate.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
            if (hasFocus) {
                dpdFecha.show();
            }
        }
    });
}

public void iniciarPicker() {
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    dpdFecha = new DatePickerDialog(this, new OnDateSetListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int dayOfMonth) {
            etDate.setText(String.valueOf(dayOfMonth) + "/" + String.valueOf(month) + "/" + String.valueOf(year));
        }
    }, cal.get(Calendar.YEAR), cal.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1, cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
}

public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_agregar_contacto_actions, menu);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.btnCancelar:
            Intent inicio = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(inicio);
            finish();
            break;
        case R.id.btnAceptar:
            Intent inicioSi = NavUtils.getParentActivityIntent(this);

            inicioSi.putExtra(getResources().getString(R.string.name), etNombre.getText().toString());
            inicioSi.putExtra(getResources().getString(R.string.phone), etTelefono.getText().toString());
            inicioSi.putExtra(getResources().getString(R.string.email), etEmail.getText().toString());
            inicioSi.putExtra(getResources().getString(R.string.date), etDate.getText().toString());
            inicioSi.putExtra(getResources().getString(R.string.description), etDescription.getText().toString());
            inicioSi.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

            startActivity(inicioSi);
            finish();
            break;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
} }
```

Si agrego un primer contacto (A) aparece en la pantalla principal:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero si agrego otro contacto (B) solo me sale este último:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Entonces lo que busco es hacer que en la lista aparezcan todos los contactos que guarde, no solo el último pero no se cómo puedo hacerlo.

Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El error es que tu agregas los valores cuando pasas de una `Activity` a otra. Entonces si en tu `MainActivity` tienes

```
Bundle contacto = getIntent().getExtras();
String nombre = contacto.getString(getResources().getString(R.string.name));
String telefono = contacto.getString(getResources().getString(R.string.phone));
String email = contacto.getString(getResources().getString(R.string.email));
String date = contacto.getString(getResources().getString(R.string.date));
String descripcion = contacto.getString(getResources().getString(R.string.description));
```

Y te vas a la `Activity` de agregar contactos, escribes los datos correspondientes y lo agregas haces eso :

```
Intent inicioSi = NavUtils.getParentActivityIntent(this);

inicioSi.putExtra(getResources().getString(R.string.name), etNombre.getText().toString());
inicioSi.putExtra(getResources().getString(R.string.phone), etTelefono.getText().toString());
inicioSi.putExtra(getResources().getString(R.string.email), etEmail.getText().toString());
inicioSi.putExtra(getResources().getString(R.string.date), etDate.getText().toString());
inicioSi.putExtra(getResources().getString(R.string.description), etDescription.getText().toString());
inicioSi.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
```

**Reemplazas** los valores que tenias anteriormente guardadas. Vas a tener que hacer lo siguiente :

Como ya tienes la clase `Contacto` y un `ArrayList` del tipo Contacto creado debes hacer esto en el `MainActivity`

```
public void agregarFab() {
FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);

    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent nuevoContacto = new Intent(MainActivity.this, AgregarContacto.class);
            intent.putExtra("contactos", nombresContactos);
            startActivity(nuevoContacto);
        }
    });
}
```

Como ves, envio de la primera `Activity` a la segunda tu `ArrayList<Contacto>` llamado `nombresContactos`.

En la segunda Activity, tienes que hacer :

```
ArrayList<Contacto> contactos = (ArrayList<Contacto>) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("contactos");
```

Cuando agregues un contacto haz esto :

```
case R.id.btnAceptar:
        String nombre = etNombre.getText().toString();
        String telefono = etTelefono.getText().toString();
        String email = etEmail.getText().toString();
        String date = etDate.getText().toString();
        String descripcion = etDescription.getText().toString();
        Contacto nuevo_contacto = new Contacto(nombre, date, descripcion, telefono, email);
        contactos.add(nuevo_contacto);
        Intent inicioSi = NavUtils.getParentActivityIntent(this);
        inicioSi.putExtra("contactos", contactos);
        startActivity(inicioSi);
        finish();
        break;
```

El nuevo contacto lo agregas a un arraylist, luego envias a tu primera `Activity` el arreglo que ahora tiene un nuevo item. Ahora solo queda modificar la primera `Activity` y dejarla asi :

```
ArrayList<Contacto> contactos = (ArrayList<Contacto>) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("contactos");
```

Comment: Muchas gracias! Tu respuesta me ayudó a solucionarlo, no pude mandar el ArrayList<Contacto> me marcaba error, pero mande cada campo del contacto como un ArrayList<String> extra en el intent, pero ahora me surgió otro problema, la primera vez después de instalar la aplicación, funciona como debe, pero si la intento abrir de nuevo se cierra y dice que la aplicación se detuvo, no tengo idea de que pueda ocasionar esto. Como sea, muchas gracias de nuevo!